# Access CIFS share using short username and not UPN

Tags: active-directory, cifs, netapp

I'm trying to configure CIFS share on my NetApp FAS2554 (NetApp Release 8.3.2P2). And I have 2 shares created. One allows accessing it using short username i.e.  and another one for some reason requires to use the full name, i.e. UPN @. And I cannot find any setting to change that to allow using short names on both shares.

Where setting should I change?

Thanks,
Best regards,
Roman